# Не работает переключение контента при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: javascript

Должно быть: нажимаю на кнопку - включается соответствующий контент. Не работает.

```js
function showIt() {
  var chart = document.getElementsByClassName('chart');
  var button = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

  function hideAll() {
    for (i = 0; i < chart.length; i++) {
      chart[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
    switch (chart[i]) {
      case chart[0]:
        hideAll();
        chart[0].style.display = 'block';
        break;
      case chart[1]:
        hideAll();
        chart[1].style.display = 'block';
        break;
      case chart[2]:
        hideAll();
        chart[2].style.display = 'block';
        break;
      case 3:
        hideAll();
        chart[3].style.display = 'block';
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.chart {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navigation">
  <a class="main" href="#url">Choose year</a>
  <li class="n2"><input type="button" value="2011" onclick="showIt()"></li>
  <li class="n3"><input type="button" value="2012" onclick="showIt()"></li>
  <li class="n4"><input type="button" value="2013" onclick="showIt()"></li>
  <li class="n5"><input type="button" value="2014" onclick="showIt()"></li>
</ul>
<div id="charts">
  <div class="chart" id="chart_div1" style="width: 100%; height: 25px;">1</div>
  <div class="chart" id="chart_div2" style="width: 100%; height: 25px;">2</div>
  <div class="chart" id="chart_div3" style="width: 100%; height: 25px;">3</div>
  <div class="chart" id="chart_div4" style="width: 100%; height: 25px;">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: [Уже проходили это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/819543/183458) несколько часов назад. Это учебное задание с заданной вёрсткой, что ли?

Comment: Нет. Я пробовал сделать это же задание на чистом JS. Всё получилось, кроме этой мелочи. Мне надо на JS понять, как это делается, без jQuery, именно в моём подходе. Какую-то мелочь упускаю. Какую - не могу понять.

Comment: Нет, не мелочь. Связка `for-switch-case`, лишенная смысла, - это, согласитесь, не мелочь. А насчет "без jQuery" - правильно ли я понимаю, что вы код, написанный с использованием jQuery, не сможете перевести в код без jQuery?

Comment: Не смогу. jQuery только поверхностно осваивал. Пока что погружаюсь в JavaScript, пробуя всё делать только с ним.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в функции `showIt` никак не определяется какая кнопка была нажата. Соответственно, и нужный блок из-за этого определить не получится.
Так как религия не позволяет мне использовать `onclick` без веских на то причин, то в ответе используется `addEventListener`. Логика же функции-обработчика события `click` от этого не меняется.

Вариант с опорой на порядок кнопок и блоков:

```js
var charts = document.getElementsByClassName("chart");
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var button of buttons) {
  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
      charts[i].style.display = (buttons[i] == this) ? "block" : "none";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.chart {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navigation">
  <a class="main" href="#url">Choose year</a>
  <li class="n2"><input type="button" value="2011" /></li>
  <li class="n3"><input type="button" value="2012" /></li>
  <li class="n4"><input type="button" value="2013" /></li>
  <li class="n5"><input type="button" value="2014" /></li>
</ul>
<div id="charts">
  <div class="chart" id="chart_div1" style="width: 100%; height: 25px;">1</div>
  <div class="chart" id="chart_div2" style="width: 100%; height: 25px;">2</div>
  <div class="chart" id="chart_div3" style="width: 100%; height: 25px;">3</div>
  <div class="chart" id="chart_div4" style="width: 100%; height: 25px;">4</div>
</div>
```

---

Более гибкий вариант с использованием data-атрибута, в котором хранится ID соответствующего блока:

```js
var charts = document.getElementsByClassName("chart");
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var button of buttons) {
  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var currentChart = document.getElementById(this.dataset.id);
    for (var chart of charts) {
      chart.style.display = (chart == currentChart) ? "block" : "none";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.chart {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navigation">
  <a class="main" href="#url">Choose year</a>
  <li class="n2"><input type="button" value="2011" data-id="chart_div1" /></li>
  <li class="n3"><input type="button" value="2012" data-id="chart_div2" /></li>
  <li class="n4"><input type="button" value="2013" data-id="chart_div3" /></li>
  <li class="n5"><input type="button" value="2014" data-id="chart_div4" /></li>
</ul>
<div id="charts">
  <div class="chart" id="chart_div1" style="width: 100%; height: 25px;">1</div>
  <div class="chart" id="chart_div2" style="width: 100%; height: 25px;">2</div>
  <div class="chart" id="chart_div3" style="width: 100%; height: 25px;">3</div>
  <div class="chart" id="chart_div4" style="width: 100%; height: 25px;">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: а через всплытие тут не более правильно? чтоб обработчки не плодить

Comment: @torokhkun нет. Во-первых, с точки зрения логики нужна обработка нажатия на кнопки - странно при этом будет видеть обработку клика на какой-то родительский элемент. Во-вторых, с точки зрения ресурсов - да, добавление одного обработчика пройдёт быстрее (хотя и тут, и там время слишком мало, чтобы за это заморачиваться), но зато при срабатывании события вариант со всплытием будет работать дольше (опять же, всё равно время несущественно для события `click`). Так что основным аргументом остаётся первый, а про второй можно вспомнить в событиях, которые генерируются много раз за секунду.